# Cross Region Lambda Function SSM

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, ssm

I have a Cloudformation template that creates several SSM configurations to include a custom default patch baseline. I included a simple Lambda Function that will set the custom patch baseline as the default with a custom resource within Cloudformation. It works great but now I need to scale this to all regions because SSM at this moment has no way to centrally manage - though I believe once I get this done AWS will have a new feature out that will do the same. The lazy way for me is to have an S3 bucket in each region and deploy my CFN through a stack set and have the lambda function created in each region. I would like to minimize resources created and have the Cloudformation trigger an SNS topic which will have the Lambda function complete the task. Does anyone have an example of how this could work or is it not possible?